# MYSQL Foreign Key Errno (150) Can't create table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, errno

I just started learning MYSQL in college and I have an important assignment to do for my class. I have to create a small database and I can't seem to add a table with foreign keys because of the errno(150)
Here's what I have.

```
create table Country
(CountryName varchar (50) not null,
Primary Key (CountryName));

create table InterestGroup
(IntrestgrpName varchar (30) not null,
Primary Key (IntrestgrpName));

create table Organisation
(OrgName varchar (50) not null,
OrgAddress varchar (30),
OrgTelNo.varchar (30),
Primary Key (OrgName));

create table Qualification
(QualName varchar (50) not null,
Primary Key (QualName));

create table Member
(MemberID varchar (15) not null,
MemberName varchar (30),
MemberAdd varchar (50) not null,
CountryName varchar (50) not null,
IntrestgrpName varchar (30) not null,
QualName varchar (50) not null,
OrgName varchar (50) not null,
Primary Key (MemberID),
Foreign Key (CountryName) References Country (CountryName),
Foreign Key (IntrestgrpName) References InterestGroup (InterestgrpName),
Foreign Key (QualName) References Qualification (Qualname),
Foreign Key (OrgName) References Organisation (OrgName));
```

I cant seem to get the Member table to be created, It gives this error,
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'iicp.member' (errno: 150)
Thanks in advance for the help, I really need to solve this

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM for the engine type? I think only InnoDB supports foreign keys. If you don't own the server itself, you might have to ask the DBA for this information.

Comment: are you sure you want MemberID varchar datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here the working query

```
create table Country
(CountryName varchar (50) not null,
Primary Key (CountryName));

create table InterestGroup
(IntrestgrpName varchar (30) not null,
Primary Key (IntrestgrpName));

create table Organisation
(OrgName varchar (50) not null,
OrgAddress varchar (30),
OrgTelNo varchar (30),
Primary Key (OrgName));

create table Qualification
(QualName varchar (50) not null,
Primary Key (QualName));

create table Member
(MemberID varchar (15) not null ,
MemberName varchar (30),
MemberAdd varchar (50) not null,
CountryName varchar (50) not null,
IntrestgrpName varchar (30) not null,
QualName varchar (50) not null,
OrgName varchar (50) not null,
Primary Key (MemberID), 
Foreign Key (CountryName) References Country (CountryName),
Foreign Key (IntrestgrpName) References InterestGroup (IntrestgrpName),
Foreign Key (QualName) References Qualification (Qualname),
Foreign Key (OrgName) References Organisation (OrgName));
```

[**DEMO  HERE SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91480)

Comment: You renamed referenced column in last table definition

Comment: nice that it worked for you! , make sure to accept the answer , to help others as helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You SQL is correct.
It worked for me with change the following change:

```
OrgTelNo.varchar (30) to OrgTelNo varchar (30)
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know that the period would have caused the table to not be entered, But wouldn't an error like this only affect the input of Organisation table though?

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;


...

------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130211 15:09:26 Error in foreign key constraint of table test/member:
Foreign Key (IntrestgrpName) References InterestGroup (InterestgrpName),
Foreign Key (QualName) References Qualification (Qualname),
Foreign Key (OrgName) References Organisation (OrgName)):
Cannot resolve column name close to:
),
Foreign Key (QualName) References Qualification (Qualname),
Foreign Key (OrgName) References Organisation (OrgName))

...
```

You referred column named **InterestgrpName** in table **InterestGroup** but actual name of column is **IntrestgrpName**

```
Foreign Key (IntrestgrpName) References InterestGroup (InterestgrpName),

You have type error here -----------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

`OrgTelNo.varchar (30),`

Instead of this you should write

`OrgTelNo varchar (30),`

And also it is a spell mistake in creation of last table member.

```
FOREIGN KEY ( IntrestgrpName ) REFERENCES InterestGroup ( IntrestgrpName)
```

Try this out instead.